# Journey Builder sdk for nodeJs

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am trying to find any sample projects or articles to guide me how to use `Jourbey Builder` from a `nodeJs` server. Is there any link available for it. 
From Journey Builder For Apps [page](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/journey-builder-for-apps/)

All I see are the sdks for `java, C#.`

Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example provided in the previous answer is great if you are looking to build a custom activity for Journey Builder.  If you are simply wanting to use NodeJS to get Subscribers into an existing interaction within Journey Builder, then there is a REST API that can be used which is documented at:
https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/events/how-to-fire-an-event.html

There is a client for Marketing Cloud REST APIs for NodeJS at:
https://github.com/ExactTarget/node-fuel

Comment: Thank you for the response. the use case I am looking at is this : Lets say a JB with a survey exists, all I am trying to do is to make a call to get this survey for a user each day and register new users to the same JB for getting these surveys from a nodejs call.

Comment: Sounds like FireEvent is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, however even before i go ahead with FireEvent, how do i insert new user who signup for this survey. Do i need to add them to a Data extension using an api ?

Comment: Yes, they will need to exist as a Subscriber record or as a record in the data extension (assuming the DE is setup as a root DE in your Contact builder model).   You can add records to data extension using the API https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/hub/data-events/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.html.  If you want to create Subscriber records, that would require use of the SOAP API.

Comment: If a new user sign-up and I just create a new DE record for him, will that be sufficient, or do need to create a Subscriber record for him too. I guess I am confused between when a new user signs-up do I need to create a Contact, Subscriber, or just a Record in DE ?

Answer (score 5):

You can refer to this [Github example](https://github.com/ExactTarget/journey-builder-custom-hello-world) - I've used this successfully earlier.

The key files to look at are

`app.js` - Triggers the sample app

`routes/activity.js` - has the various activity handling methods

`public/javascript/scripts.js` - shows a simple Hello World app using Journey Builder

Feel free to post another thread if you run into any issues.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I went over the git example. Can you clarify this use case for me, if thats possible with it :Thank you for the response. the use case I am looking at is this : Lets say a JB with a survey exists, all I am trying to do is to make a call to get this survey for a user each day and another part is to register new users to the same JB from a nodejs call.